# How to get AUTOMOC to find header file in QT5

Tags: qt, cmake, automoc

I'm using Qt 5 and I put all my headers in separate include folders, and AUTOMOC is unable to find my headers.

```
src
 |- sim
     |- include
         |- sim
            |- client.h (contains Q_OBJECT)
     |- client.cpp
```

My CMake Code:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
add_library(client client.cpp)
target_include_directories(client PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_link_libraries(client sim Qt5::Widgets)
```

This results in undefined references to my signals because the QObject MOC class  in client is not being generated. I tried adding this to force it to search for client.h...

```
#include "moc_client.cpp"
```

However then I get the error

```
AutoMoc error
-------------
  "/home/peter/projects/smartmouse/smartmouse-simulator/src/sim/client.cpp"
The file includes the moc file "moc_client.cpp", but the header "client.{h,hh,h++,hm,hpp,hxx,in,txx}" could not be found.
```

I get why this is, because the docs only say it searches the current folder so it's not going to look int the `include/sim` folder. My question is **how do I get AUTOMOC to find include/sim/client.h?**

I also tried using qt5_wrap_cpp but it doesn't seem to actually call the moc compiler, it only sets up some information. I tried:

```
qt5_wrap_cpp(client include/sim/client.h)
```

But it did not generate any cmake targets as far as I can tell

EDIT:

I've also noticed in the `AutogenInfo.cmake` file that no header is found: `set(AM_HEADERS "")`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this similar issue and while I'm not satisfied with this answer, it might be helpful.

`CMAKE_AUTOMOC` is not picking up `client.cpp`'s `#include "sim/client.h"` but you can manually add it to the target sources:

`add_library(client client.cpp include/sim/client.h)`

Comment: Didn't help for me.